# How to uninstall node.js

Tags: node.js

Even though I have no idea what it is I have installed node.js

I would now like to uninstall it from my Mac (Monterey OS and M1). But I can't find Node.js in the Applications folder and the only info I can find online are very complicated Terminal instructions. Again, I have no idea what Terminal is and do not want to have to use it.

Is there an uninstaller? Or easy way to uninstall it?

Comment: No. I have looked at that page before posting, but didn't understand a word of it

Comment: You may only need to run `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp` in your command line.

Comment: *"I have no idea what Terminal is and do not want to have to use it."* - Then you're out of luck, because NodeJS (along with many, many other programs) is a command-line tool.  A Google search for "macos remove node js" finds a variety of helpful resources, but all of them are going to involve using a terminal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Complete uninstall Node.js on macOS Monterey version 12.0.1

To check the current node version installed on your system:

```
# node -v
# v14.15.0
```

Enter the given below commands to delete Node from your system:

```
# cd /usr/local/include
# sudo rm -R node
# cd ../lib
# sudo rm -R node_modules
# cd ../bin
# sudo rm -R node
```

to check that node doesn't exist anymore

```
# node -v
# -bash: node: command not found //if  this came that means it uninstall successfully
```

Comment: I get the following:
# node -v
#zsh: command not found: node
(does that mean it has been successfully uninstalled?)

Comment: yes it has been successfully uninstall

Comment: Thank you, that has been a great help